# Gives me headaches or headache

Tags: word-choice

Should I use the singular or the plural form of "headache" in my sentence?

"I love rain when the thunderstorm thunders. I like sunny weather when it's light all around.These changes in the weather can give me headaches/ a headache.The weather also has a mood. It changes so quickly where I live."

Comment: Grammatically, either one, though usually and idiomatically one would use the singular.

Comment: Thank you. Do you find the rest of the context unnatural? In my language I can say that the weather has a mood too like people and thunderstorms thunder ... but does this sound natural as well as the rest of the text?

Comment: You can say what you like. Generally, we don't say the weather has a mood, though. We do say: angry clouds. For example.

Comment: I was looking for the verb  for "thunderstorm thunders."  :S

Comment: Thunder can crackle. Thunder can create a large bang. :) The storm came thundering down the canyon. :) A stroke of lightening can crack the sky.

Comment: Thank you! I see now.

Comment: @Lambie - lovers of roast pork might say a stroke of crackling can lighten the sky.

Comment: For me, the problem is that you start by saying you love it, but then abruptly say it causes something negative (headaches). I would add the transition “However” before “these changes” to account for the shift in opinion.

Comment: I see. Thank you, SegNerd. Should  "when it's light all around" be also rephrased, Lambie? You said I can say what I like, but does it sound natural?

Comment: Is this meant to be prose or poetry?  Unusual expressions are OK and often good in poetry.

Comment: It's from my friend's poems.